# Why do I have to requestFileSystem inside onDeviceReady?

Tags: javascript, android, file, cordova

I am using PhoneGap's File API (W3C File). All file read examples force you to call window.requestFileSystem(...) inside onDeviceReady...why?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a file from an SD card in PhoneGap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590816/how-to-read-a-file-from-an-sd-card-in-phonegap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to make sure that Cordova/Phonegap is ready.

From Cordova 1.6.1's source code, line 431:

- onDeviceReady              User event fired to indicate that Cordova is ready

Until this event is fired you can't be sure that Phonegap's ready for you. 
requestFileSystem is defined in: lib/common/plugin/requestFileSystem.js

Answer (score 0):

Becose in onDeviceReady  certainly exists window.requestFileSystem